# How to properly convert a C ioctl call to a python fcntl.ioctl call?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ioctl, fcntl

Following an example on [resetting a serial port](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-reset-usb-device-in-linux/) in Linux I wanted to translate the following snippet

```
fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0);
close(fd);
```

into valid python code. Here is what I have tried so far

```
file_handler = open(self._port, 'w')
fcntl.ioctl(file_handler, termios.USBDEVFS_RESET)
file_handler.close()
```

which ends with an error `'module' object has no attribute 'USBDEVFS_RESET'`. The [termios documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html#module-termios) is not very helpful in this point, as it does not list the possible properties of `termios`. See also the [fcntl documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) for an example of such a `termios` property.

How to I 'convert' the C code to python2.7 code correctly?

Answer (score 12):

I came across this when looking how to do a USBDEVFS_RESET and thought I'd share what I found about _IO:  https://web.archive.org/web/20140430084413/http://bugcommunity.com/wiki/index.php/Develop_with_Python#Introduction_to_ioctl_calls_in_python

So, what I have so far is the following:

```
from fcntl import ioctl

busnum = 1
devnum = 10

filename = "/dev/bus/usb/{:03d}/{:03d}".format(busnum, devnum) 

#define USBDEVFS_RESET             _IO('U', 20)
USBDEVFS_RESET = ord('U') << (4*2) | 20

fd = open(filename, "wb")
ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)
fd.close()
```

You can get the `busnum` and `devnum` from `lsusb`.

EDIT: above link was dead, URL was replaced to the last archived version.

Answer (score 6):

[ioctl-opt](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-ioctl-opt) ([pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ioctl-opt)) is a small python module translating needed C preprocessor macros to python.
For a simple usage example, see this [hidraw](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-hidraw/blob/master/hidraw/__init__.py) implementation.

Note that defining ctype structures can be needed (depending on call type) so you can actually pass parameters.

Disclosure: I am the author of both modules.

Answer (score 0):

The macro `USBDEVFS_RESET` is defined in a system header file somewhere.

You can search for it and replace `termios.USBDEVFS_RESET` with the actual value.

Comment: The value `USBDEVFS_RESET` has the value `_IO('U', 20)`. I do not need to try your suggestion to see that this won't work. So the original question remains unanswered. Maybe you know what `_IO('U', 20)` is? Replacing `termios.USBDEVFS_RESET` simply by `20` gives the error: `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`.

Comment: @Alex Then look what `_IO` does, and if it uses another macro look at that. In the end an integer will be created through some bit manipulation, and that integer can be used in Python.

Comment: You are right, the value '20' is just the beginning. I finally found the correct implementation of `_IO` and got a value of 21780. HOWEVER, with `termios.USBDEVFS_RESET` in my example code replaced by `21780` I again get the error `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. I suspect that I miss something, or that the first argument to `fcntl.ioctl` is not a simple integer value.

Comment: The variable seem to be a simple int, so something else is wrong.