# Beaglebone Black watchdog in Python

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, ioctl, watchdog

I have a Beaglebone Black running Debian and I need a script running in background, which would check every few seconds if the system is still running. As far as I understand, watchdog in BBB is hardware-based and runs independently from OS, so it can reboot the device even if OS is completely frozen (right?). Here is a very simple example from [logicsupply](http://inspire.logicsupply.com/2014/08/beaglebone-using-watchdog-timer.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import os

os.nice(20)
time.sleep(60)                  # Wait before starting
wd = open("/dev/watchdog", "w+")
while 1:
     wd.write("\n")
     wd.flush()
     time.sleep(5)
```

But I can't find a way to change default timeout. In C it would look like:

`ioctl(fd, WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout);`

But calling ioctl functions in Python seems to be rather obscure. From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626395/how-to-properly-convert-a-c-ioctl-call-to-a-python-fcntl-ioctl-call) it seems like C macro definitions may have different values depending on hardware. Is there a convenient way to address them (at least, this particular one, to change default watchdog timeout) in Python?
And what is the best way to run the script in background so that it could reboot the system with a frozen OS?

Comment: Can you not do this from the watchdog conf or use the pid? Do you actually want to reboot if the script fails?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham BBB will be used as a controller in a mobile robot. If there is a problem with OS or control software (crash/freeze), we need to restore control as soon as possible. That's why I would like to go as low-level as possible.

Comment: I am not overly familiar with watchdog but looking at the manpage, I thought setting the interval woud work http://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it works, thanks! I've abandoned the idea of making it through ioctl, instead changing .conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750547/beaglebone-black-watchdog-in-python#comment47646032_29750547) by [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) has directed me to the [manpage for watchdog.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf) which is the right and working way to configure the hardware WDT on AM335x, so there's no need for additional scripts/daemons:

```
watchdog-timeout = 10
```